# to change WinHttpSettings registry value

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to change 'WinHttpSettings'  Registry value but it's giving error. I tried like below

```
       RegistryKey OurKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
        //MessageBox.Show(OurKey.ToString());
        RegistryKey local = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections");
        string value = local.GetValue("WinHttpSettings").ToString();
        byte[] b ={ 1, 1, 1, 1 };
        if (value != null)
        {
            local.SetValue("WinHttpSettings",b);
            //MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
        }
```

Any mistake i done in above code or any other  solution

before in registry the value is like below:

[image: before]

after doing 'Steve B' told change:

```
 RegistryKey local = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections",true);
```

[image]

but i wanted is to change first image values as '0000'

Comment: 'Cannot write to the registry key.'

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
RegistryKey local = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
    @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections",
    true
    );
```

Especially, notice the `true` as second argument. As explained in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d.aspx), its use is :

```
 writable Type: System.Boolean 
 Set to true if you need write access to the
 key.
```

Comment: now it changed value to '0*00000000(1)' but i wanted to change the value to '0000' i.e before it's having some hexadecimal value i wanted to remove that

Comment: not sure to understand your goal. what do you write four 1 byte, and not four 0 ?

Comment: still not understanding.... put `byte[] b ={ 0, 0, 0, 0 }` if you want 4 bytes filled with 0

Comment: when i deleted manually zero bytes it's showing like '0 0 0 0'

Comment: You may also force the type of value in order to keep the same type as the previous version using `local.SetValue("WinHttpSettings", b,RegistryValueKind.Binary);`

Comment: It's giving that error because of 'UnauthorizedAccessException'. May be with admin privilege only we can do

Comment: you have to run your app using elevated privileges (run as admin)

Comment: i can run but i am using this code for my utility. If client don't have admin privilege then it's no use of writing this code

Comment: this is the UAC... you **have** to run with elevated privilege